# global tabbar problem in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am implementing a web based application.  In this app I need a tab bar that appears on all screens.

I have implemented a tab bar screen and all my screen classes extend it.  The tab bar is visible on all screens but it is not working properly on all screens.

Comment: I think you are going to have to explain how it should work, and be specific about how that isn't happening on some of the screens.  We need details.   If you have a _short_ code snippet that doesn't work, that would help as well.   Dumping the entire class into StackOverflow is not useful, however.

Comment: thanks for reply Mr. Michael... actually i am implementing a application in this app i want to create one common tab bar for all screens in bottom side.